# How can I use juju manage multiple environments?

Tags: juju

If I have multiple juju environments defined, I will often want to run a series of commands on one of them.  Specifying -e on every call is rather tedious, but changing the default every time you switch projects is also annoying.  Is there an environment variable I can set in my shell session to specify which environment all subsequent juju commands should be run against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to manage Juju environments within the command line. One way is to set the "default" YAML key to the environment you want to use by default:

```
default: devel
environments:
  production:
    ...
  devel:
    ...
  staging:
    ...
```

You can override the `default` environments.yaml key by passing an `-e` flag with each Juju command, the value set to which environment you want to use:

```
juju bootstrap -e staging
juju deploy -e staging mysql
juju status -e production
juju destroy-environment -e devel
```

Lastly, Juju will [look for the `JUJU_ENV` environment variable](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-choose-between-environments). You can export that then reset it to either an empty string or a new value to avoid changing the `default` environments.yaml key or using the `-e` flag

```
marco@work:~$ export JUJU_ENV=production
marco@work:~$ juju bootstrap
2012-11-14 13:55:44,235 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'production' (origin: ppa type: ec2)...
2012-11-14 13:55:45,567 INFO 'bootstrap' command finished successfully

marco@work:~$ export JUJU_ENV=local
marco@work:~$ juju status
2012-11-14 13:55:39,504 INFO Connecting to environment...
2012-11-14 13:55:40,179 ERROR juju environment not found: is the environment bootstrapped?
```